# Oracle db impdp command syntax error

Tags: oracle, sqlplus, impdp

I'm trying to run 
`impdp system/password dumpfile=FILE.dmp fromuser=USER1 touser=USER1 directory=$DIRECTORY` on oracle server but keep getting following error:

- LRM-00118: syntax error at '=' at the end of input

I've come to this after running the following commands on oracle server sqlplus:

- `alter session set container=sgeplus;`
- `CREATE USER USER1 IDENTIFIED BY USER1;`
- `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES TO USER1 WITH ADMIN OPTION;`
- `GRANT CONNECT TO USER1;`
- `CREATE USER GEOC_WEB IDENTIFIED BY GEOC_WEB;`
- `GRANT CONNECT TO GEOC_WEB;`

And running this on oracle server:

- `expdp sgeplus/sgeplus@localhost/orcl full=y dumpfile=sge210b.dmp`

I haven't found any similar error, so any help will be welcomed!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Fromuser and touser are not valid using datapump. If you are trying to change the schema, you can use remap_schema:

```
REMAP_SCHEMA=source_schema:target_schema
```

https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SUTIL/GUID-619809A6-1966-42D6-9ACC-A3E0ADC36523.htm#SUTIL927

Or you can list which schemas to import:

```
SCHEMAS=schema_name [,...]
```

https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SUTIL/GUID-6FEDE3AF-0ED5-46D6-BE91-C3F840291735.htm#SUTIL931

Answer (score 0):

You have to use syntax like given below:

```
impdp USER/PASSWORD@SERVICE_NAME directory=DIRECTORY_NAME dumpfile=DUMPFILE.dmp logfile=LOGFILE.log REMAP_SCHEMA=SOURCE_SCHEMA:TARGET_SCHEMA
```

> Where, 
>   source_schema = user1 target_schema = user2 logfile and service name are optional.